# Different process open same file for different mode of operation

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, filesystems

I was revising linux file descriptors, open file table in kernel and came across this post on [medium.com](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/the-method-to-epolls-madness-d9d2d6378642), here it mentions

> Let’s assume fd5 is created as a result of process A calling open on file abc.txt for **reading**. Let us assume process B also calls openon abc.txt but for **writing** and the file descriptor the open call returns to process B is fd10.
>
> Then process A’s fd5 and process B’s fd10 point to different open file descriptions in the open file table, but they point to the same inode table entry (or in other words, the same file).

Here is the pictorial representation.
[image]

I get the fact that they point to same inode entry, however, is this correct that if file is opened for different operations it will have 2 different open file entries in kernel ?
Since I believe there is a common offset per file, whether it is for reading or writing.

Just needed some clarifications, thanks

Comment: "is this correct that if file is opened for different operations it will have 2 different open file entries in kernel?" - Yes, this is correct. Every `open` call results in new instance of opened file entry.

Comment: Actually, there is no such thing like "Open File Table" in the kernel: opened files has no index and cannot be searched. That is, when another process opens some file, it simply cannot check whether given file has already been opened. (But inodes can be searched).

Comment: But in the above diagram, fd0, fd4 or process A and fd0 of process B are pointing to same kernel file entry

Comment: "But in the above diagram, fd0, fd4 or process A and fd0 of process B are pointing to same kernel file entry" - The diagram is wrong: According to it, files opened by different processes share current file offset. But actually file offsets are not shared between processes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev File offsets belong to the open file description, not the process. The same open file description may be shared by multiple processes as they are inherited by the new process after `fork()` or the new process/thread after `clone()` with the `CLONE_FILES` flag.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, I know that sharing file offsets is possible between child and parent processes. When wrote my previous comment I forgot to note that specific. In any case, OP doesn't mention child-parent relation between processes in the example.

Comment: As @Tsyvarev wrote, there is no "Open File Table" at least in current versions of the kernel. Each row in your table is a separate `struct file` object not part of a table. They are allocated dynamically by `__alloc_file()` (since kernel 4.19) or `get_empty_filp()` (before kernel 4.19) in "fs/file_table.c" .